# Installing rvm: running into problems with permissions

Tags: macos, terminal, rvm

I receive this error message whilst trying to install rvm on OS X:

```
fatal: Unable to create '/usr/local/.git/index.lock': Permission denied
Error: Failure while executing: git checkout -q master
Failed to update Homebrew, follow instructions here:
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Common-Issues
and make sure `brew update` works before continuing.
```

Here is my original command (as instructed on the rvm website)

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails --autolibs=enabled
```

I went to the 'Common Issues' page and there is nothing there mentioning this error -
To give you some background - I have the app Gitbox installed which the only client that manages any git commits - I also have previously installed Homebrew a few months ago. I tried to run `sudo brew update` - it gave me this log:

`Already up-to-date.`

Comment: Have try this ? JewelryBox - The Official OS X RVM GUI

Comment: @Strik3r I've just downloaded it - it seems a nice way to manage ruby gems - but does this app automatically install rvm for me?

Comment: Yes. Try it is nice app

Comment: For `Permission denied` try sudo command . `\curl -L https://get.rvm.io |sudo bash -s stable --rails --autolibs=enabled`

Comment: Thank you @Strik3r that worked perfectly - post this as an answer and i'll accept.